# How to avoid computation in request.security_lower_tf

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to avoid computation in `request.security_lower_tf` selectively by using a flag `skip_lower_tf` which whenever is set as true I want to not calculate/use `request.security_lower_tf`.

I tried `skip_lower_tf?na:(request.security_lower_tf())`, but it is not working, and even when I have the `skip_lower_tf=true` it seems that the computation still happens.

For example, when my chart timeframe is lower than the timeframe of `security_lower_tf` and `skip_lower_tf=true` I still get the error complaining about the timeframe of `security_lower_tf`  should be lower than the chart timeframe.
I am wondering how I can skip going through the `security_lower_tf` computation when I have `skip_lower_tf=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the job

```
request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, skip_lower_tf ? '' : timeframe, ...)
```